# Get element's :hover size without actually hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I know it's possible to [get an a:hover color without hovering on the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651337/is-it-possible-to-get-an-ahover-color-via-javascript-without-hovering-on-the-el), but what about it's width and height? If the link's size is `auto`, it can't be read from the stylesheets. I'm intending to do some experimental trickery with links that hover to bold. Is my only option binding to the hover event?

Comment: You can get with javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

you could solve it in a similar way like with the colors.
if you extract all informations from the stylesheet that would influence the width.
and apply it to a temporary element with the same content of the link.
then you could calculate the width.

if you create the stylesheet yourself it would be easier if you create a css rule like this.

```
a:hover, a.hover {}
```

and then temporary add the class .hover to the link and calculate its size.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery), but changing it up to add the styling to the `span` so that it matches the styling of your `a:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if there is no matter of performance leaks,
i can suggest a simpler way, use jquery `.trigger()` to trigger a `mouseover` event on the desired element and then take its width, it can give you a more practical size than the other ways. although you can use it async to other scripts and functions for not affecting your page.